# Save blender file startup export preferences (2.92)

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have been consistently making videos, and I was wondering if there was a way to save my video preferences before exporting; for example audio codec, location ffmpeg video etc. I know on older updates you could go to

```
file --> save startup file
```

but I can't seem to find that in this version. Any help is great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I just found it is under

```
file --> defaults--> save startup file
```